# Best choice for runtime templating engine?

Tags: templates, xslt, razor, transform, t4

We're designing an app that will generate lots of different types of text output, eg email, html, sms, etc. The output will be generated using some kind of template, with data coming from a db.  Our requirements include:

1. Basic logic / calculated fields within template. Eg "ifs" and "for" loops, plus some things like adding percentages for tax etc
2. Runtime editing. Our users need to be able to tweak the templates to their needs, such as change boilerplate text, add new logic, etc
3. Multi lingual. We need to choose the correct template for the current culture.
4. Culture sensitive. Eg dates and currencies will output according to current ui culture.
5. Flexibility. We need the templates to be able to handle multiple repeating groups, hierarchies, etc.
6. Cannot use commercial software as a solution (e.g. InfoPath). We need to be able to modify the source code at any time.

The app is c#.net. We are considering using T4, XML + XSLT or hosting the Razor engine. Given that the syntax cant be too overwhelming for non-techie users, we'd like to get your opinion on which you feel is the right templating engine for us. We're happy to consider ones notalready mentioned too.

Thanks.

Comment: Simon, AFAIK Razor is an application of T4. Thus I believe there is no reason to distinguish between these two. As for "non techie users", you may be interested in InfoPath.

Comment: Dimitre, thanks for your reply. Razor is built on top of T4 but I have to take in to account the syntax for the user. Is it easy enough for them to use, etc. Also I cannot use a commercial application like InfoPath. The solution needs to be either built in to .NET (T4, Razor, XSLT, etc.) or an open source solution.

Comment: T4 is built into Visual Studio, not the .NET framework. It cannot be redistributed and only allows you to ship "runtime" / "preprocessed" templates, which cannot be modified. Razor and T4 have no common technology.

Comment: @OlegSych thanks for this. Didn't know T4 wasn't part of .NET! Well that's one less engine to worry about then. What would you go for?

Comment: If you need to generate markup and know how to host the Razor engine, that may be your best option. I haven't tried that route though. Personally, I would stay away from XSLT - no user I ever met would know how to build anything but trivial transformations. Years ago, company I worked for used an open source text templating engine called NVelocity. I don't know the current status of this project.

Comment: Yes, I've successfully hosted Razor is another project and it worked really well. I guess I'll just stick to what I know!

Comment: @OlegSych I will check out NVelocity too. Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: There is also an independent Mono implementation of T4, which of course is redistributable via its OSS license.

Comment: @GarethJ thanks for your message. Will check it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We've decided to go with Razor Hosting. The reason why I've posted this is an answer is that I thought it would help others if I include the following article link:

http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2010/Dec/27/Hosting-the-Razor-Engine-for-Templating-in-NonWeb-Applications

This excellent piece of work by Rick Strahl makes it really easy to host Razor.

Answer (score 3):

I'm very hesitant to try and answer this question on a forum, because technology choices depend on far more factors than are conveyed in the question, including things such as attitude to risk, attitude to open source, previous good and bad experiences, politics and leadership on the project etc. The big advantage of XSLT over Razor is that it's a standard and has multiple implementations on multiple platforms (including at least three implementations on .NET!) so there's no lock-in; but that doesn't seem to be a factor in your statement of requirements. And the fact that you're using .NET suggests that supplier lock-in isn't something that worries you anyway.

One thing to bear in mind is that non-programmers often take to XSLT a lot more quickly than programmers do. Its rule-based declarative approach, and its XML syntax, sometimes make programmers uncomfortable (it's not like anything they have seen before) but end-users often take to it like ducks to water.

Comment: Michael, thank you for your reply and I appreciate your comments. I hadn't considered that non-programmers would take to XSLT faster than devs but you're right that the declarative approach does sometimes make me uncomfortable! However, I do find the XSLT syntax very unforgiving. It's also case sensitive which non-devs hate. In terms of our attitude to risk, we're happy to try anything that's going to work; there are no politics issues since there are only two of us in our company! Certainly willing to try open source; But we do not to be able to modify the source so commercial apps are out.

Comment: XSLT was developed by ivory tower types whose solutions work well in theory, but horribly in practice. XSLT has a dearth of provisions to handle even the most trivial string processing, such as trim, tokenize, etc. After a few hours of using it, you're craving a real programming language. Moreover, as you move past trivial transformations, the document structure gets lost in a forestry of tags. Razor, T4, while they have their own issues, the resulting markup is clearer to non-programmers.

Comment: @ATL_DEV Sounds like you've never advanced beyond version 1.0, which is 23 years old. Any technology can be frustrating after a few hours: it takes a lot more than that to discover its strengths.

Comment: I am currently evaluating several templating technologies for code generation and XSLT is one of them. So far, XSLT 2.0 makes it super hard to control the formatting. I'm sure it's great for regular XML.

Comment: If you have a question, I suggest you ask it as a question, not as a comment on a post from ten years ago. Especially a post that should probably have been closed on the grounds that this kind of post tends to attract opinionated answers.